# Massive Delete statement - How to improve query execution time?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance

I have a Spring batch that will run everyday to :

1. Read CSV files and import them into our database
2. Aggregate this data and save these aggregated data into another table.

We have a table `BATCH_LIST` that contains information about all the batchs that were already executed.

`BATCH_LIST` has the following columns :

```
 1. BATCH_ID
 2. EXECUTION_DATE
 3. STATUS
```

Among the CSV files that are imported, we have one CSV file to feed a `APP_USERS` table, and another one to feed the `ACCOUNTS` table.

`APP_USERS` has the following columns :

```sql
 1. USER_ID
 2. BATCH_ID
 -- more columns
```

`ACCOUNTS` has the following columns :

```sql
 1. ACCOUNT_ID
 2. BATCH_ID
 -- more columns
```

In step 2, we aggregate data from `ACCOUNTS` and `APP_USERS`  to insert rows into a `USER_ACCOUNT_RELATION` table. This table has exactly two columns : `ACCOUNT_ID` (refering to `ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_ID`) and `USER_ID`  (refering to `APP_USERS.USER_ID`).

Now we want to add another step in our Spring batch. We want to delete all the data from  `USER_ACCOUNT_RELATION` table but also `APP_USERS` and `ACCOUNTS`  that are no longer relevant (ie data that was imported before `sysdate - 2`.

What has been done so far :

1. Get all the `BATCH_ID` that we want to remove from the database

   ```sql
   SELECT BATCH_ID FROM BATCH_LIST WHERE trunc(EXECUTION_DATE) < sysdate - 2
   ```
2. For each `BATCH_ID`, we are calling the following methods :

   ```java
    public void deleteAppUsersByBatchId(Connection connection, long batchId) throws SQLException  
     // prepared statements to delete User account relation and user
   ```

And here are the two prepared statements :

```sql
DELETE FROM USER_ACCOUNT_RELATION 
WHERE USER_ID IN (
   SELECT USER_ID FROM APP_USERS WHERE BATCH_ID = ?
);
```

```sql
DELETE FROM APP_USERS WHERE BATCH_ID = ?
```

My issue is that it takes too long to delete data for one `BATCH_ID` (more than 1 hour).

Note : I only mentioned the `APP_USERS`, `ACCOUNTS` AND `USER_ACCOUNT_RELATION` tables, but I actually have around 25 tables to delete.

How can I improve the query time ?
(I've just tried to change the `WHERE USER_ID IN ()` into an `EXISTS`. It is better but still way too long.

Comment: How many those XX do you have? Where do you get them from?

Comment: Now, I have 70 of them. Each day, we receive files that are imported into the database. In production environment, I won't have as many FILE_ID as I have in my test environment.

Comment: Add indexes to USER and ACCOUNT on the FILE_ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to do that at first (that's why I added the note on the indices) but I've read somewhere that the more indices you have, the slower the delete will be.

Comment: @sewey can you query all those XXX in subquery?

Comment: do you have partitioning option? The easiest way to delete data is to drop whole partition

Comment: seems strange to me that you want to " delete data that was inserted in the last two days." but there is no reference to a date . . .  what does FILE_ID represent?

Comment: @EdStevens : I didn't mention it but I have also a table FILE that has an ID column and an IMPORT_DATE column.  What we do is a first query to retrieve all the FILE_ID where trunc(IMPORT_DATE) < (sysdate - 2), and then pass these file_id to the DELETE query.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov no, we don't have partitioning options. As for the subquery option, you would write something like "Delete from ACCOUNT where exists (select FILES.ID from FILES where FILES.id = account.file_id"?

Comment: @sewey ` I have also a table FILE that has an ID column` - FILE is a reserved word in oracle. Can you show us real query?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov , yes sorry. I didn't want to get into the details at first. Let me edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that will be your regular process, ie you want to store only last 2 days, you don't need indexes, since every time you will delete 1/3 of all rows.

It's better to use just 3 deletes instead of 3*7 separate deletes:

```sql
DELETE FROM USER_ACCOUNT_RELATION 
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID IN
(
  SELECT u.ID 
  FROM {USER} u 
  join {FILE} f
       on u.FILE_ID = f.file
  WHERE trunc(f.IMPORT_DATE) < (sysdate - 2)
);

DELETE FROM {USER}
  WHERE FILE_ID in (select FILE_ID from {file} where trunc(IMPORT_DATE) < (sysdate - 2));
  
DELETE FROM {ACCOUNT}
  WHERE FILE_ID in (select FILE_ID from {file} where trunc(IMPORT_DATE) < (sysdate - 2));
```

Just replace `{USER}`, `{FILE}`, `{ACCOUNT}` with your real table names.

Obviously in case of partitioning option it would be much easier - daily interval partitioning, so you could easily drop old partitions.

But even in your case, there is also another more difficult but really fast solution - "partition views": for example for ACCOUNT, you can create 3 different tables ACCOUNT_1, ACCOUNT_2 and ACCOUNT_3, then create partition view:

```sql
create view ACCOUNT as
select 1 table_id, a1.* from ACCOUNT_1 a1
union all
select 2 table_id, a2.* from ACCOUNT_2 a2
union all
select 3 table_id, a3.* from ACCOUNT_3 a3;
```

Then you can use instead of trigger on this view to insert daily data into own table: first day into account_1,second - account_2, etc. And truncate old table each midnight. You can easily get table name using

```sql
select 'ACCOUNT_'|| (mod(to_char(sysdate, 'j'),3)+1) tab_name from dual;
```

Comment: thanks. I've just tried the subquery solution but I'm getting a ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired error. The idea of splitting the table into 3 is interesting too. however, if i need to change the number of days from 2 to another number, what would be your recommendation ?